# How to get value from array with index in INSERT statement inside postgresql procedure?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

```
CREATE TABLE public.tbl_test 
(
    pk_test_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    dbl_amount DOUBLE PRECISION,
    dbl_usd_amount DOUBLE PRECISION 
);
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.sp_insert_or_update_test(IN jsnData jsonb)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
    BEGIN
            INSERT INTO public.tbl_test (
                dbl_amount,
                dbl_usd_amount)
             VALUES(
                CAST(jsnData->>'dbl_amount' AS DOUBLE PRECISION[]) ->> 0,  
                CAST(jsnData->>'dbl_amount' AS DOUBLE PRECISION[]) ->> 1
            );

        RETURN;
    END;
$BODY$;
```

USAGE:

```
CALL sp_insert_or_update_test('{ "dbl_amount": [1, 2] }'::jsonb);
```

Issue:

Here in the `INSERT` statement, I am trying to insert 2 values from array using array-index. But it's not working.

```
CAST(jsnData->>'dbl_amount' AS DOUBLE PRECISION[]) ->> 0
```

Expecting a solution (Fn/Operator) to get value from array with index in INSERT statement inside postgresql procedure.

Comment: Why pass two double values hidden in a JSON value? Why not declare the procedure with two parameters directly?

Comment: In Question example, only provided 1 array. In my real use case, I have about 90 similar amount arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the `dbl_amount` key as a JSONB, not as a text, so the first operator should be `->`. And then you need to cast the result of the final `->>` operator, not the intermediate JSONB value. And the result should be a `double precision` not an array of `double precision`

```
CAST( (jsnData -> 'dbl_amount' ->> 0) AS DOUBLE PRECISION),
```